# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker crash on Windows 10

Tags: ros2, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the [tutorial to install ROS 2 Humble on Windows 10](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html), I am stuck at [this point](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html#try-some-examples) where I am unable to start a basic example:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 3221226505
```

I am getting the exact same error from both the DOS CMD and the Windows PowerShell in both admin and user modes.

Any idea on how to debug this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404093/ros2-run-demo_nodes_cpp-talker-crash-on-windows-10/) by [Olivier Michel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13651/olivier-michel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the reason for this crash: my `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` environment variable was containing a non-integer value. Setting it to an integer value fixed the crash... I hoped to get a more user-friendly message to debug this..

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Michel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13651/olivier-michel/) with karma: 31 on 2022-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nevermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/124553/nevermind/) on 2022-11-21**:
I have this exact problem, but I don't have a ROS_DOMAIN_ID environment variable, I tried setting it to integer value anyway, but I still have the same issue. I don't know where the problem could be, could you give me any pointers on what else I should look for.